# call useRef inside a useEffect got Invalid hook call error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How do I create ref for element that doesn't exist yet?

I have a dynamic form, how do I create ref for each input? the form has an add new input options, so I have to dynamically create a new ref each time user clicked on add new input?

I got an error doing this, won't work:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const inputRef = useMemo(() => Array(totalInput).fill(0).map(i => useRef()), []);
  }, [createdInput])
```

but if I do this

```
const inputRef = useMemo(() => Array(totalInput).fill(0).map(i => useRef()), []);
console.log(inputRef)
```

inputRef only have 1 item in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the inputs are dynamic, rather than using a ref for each, you might consider using DOM methods instead, and a single ref for the parent. For example:

```
return (
  <div ref={containerRef}>
    {inputDatas.map(inputData => <Input inputData={inputData} />)}
  </div>
);
```

And then to select the `n`th input, use:

```
containerRef.current.children[n]
```

The selection method to use will depend on your input structure. You might want something like `containerRef.current.querySelectorAll('input')[n]`.

Comment: it's not advisable, I have multiple kind of input and other component from 3rd party, it's better to use ref on each kind of input

Comment: Then examine the HTML structure to determine what sort of selector you need to select only the inputs you're interested in. Just for example, `querySelectorAll('input:nth-child(2)')` will select `<input>`s which are the 2nd child of its parent. Or, `'span + input'` to select `<input>`s which come right after a `<span>`. CSS selectors are extraordinarily flexible and concise.